# About passive rules

Tags: past-tense, passive-voice, auxiliary-verbs, past-participles

There is a sentence that I can't understand:

"There are around 7000 languages *spoken* in the world."

Shouldn't we say??? :

"are spoken"

Where is the auxiliary verb?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

"spoken around the world" is a participle phrase. It is often possible to convert a participle phrase to a relative clause.

Your sentence is equivalent to:

> There are around 7000 languages that are spoken in the world."

But English allows the use of participle phrases to modify nouns. The given sentence is correct English. As are

> This is a book *written by my sister*.

or

> An apple *eaten by a worm* is no good for a pie.

(Participle phrases in *italics*)

Comment: Thank you for your help ✨